# Having an akward issue with htaccess (rewritecond / rewriterule)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Basically I want rewrite engine to kill any URI's that have ".php" in it.

So I've got this, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\.php)+$
RewriteRule ^/$ 404[L]
```

Even just RewriteRule ^(.*.php)+/$ 404 doesnt' work.

Maybe my brain is stunned from working on this proj all day, so it could be a little error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a RewriteRule that redirects a URI to a php file; it becomes a loop hole with the first cond being ^(php).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(login|register)$ $1.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/(login|register)(\.php)? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule (.*) 404 [L]
```

the (login|register|etc...) are the file name. It means: login OR register OR some other file if you have more than one. If you only have 1 you can use (login) or login

Comment: This would work perfect, but I just figured out my issue.  The fact is that I've already got a dozen URI aliases that redirect to php files.  So I think apache's denying those redirects too, basically creating a loophole.

Comment: RewriteRule ^login(/*)$ login.php

Comment: Do you have more than one PHP file like login?